# How to create linq query to join rows into string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I have a table with the following fields:

Id Name Score Event

(1   John 2    3)
(2   John 4    3)
(3   john 5    3)

and I would like to get the following result:

(John, "2 +4+5", 11(Total score))

I'm trying to combine the results to show the sum in a string format then show the sum result.
Can anyone please help me with this issue.
Thank you,
Franciso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `toList()` method before using methods like `string.Format` or `string.Join` because they are not supported by Linq to SQL.

You should modify your code into something like this:

```
var group = (from Classificacao in _dbSet.classificacao
                 from Evento in _dbSet.evento
                 where Classificacao.class_id_Evento == id_evento
                 where Evento.id_evento == id_evento
                 group Classificacao by new
                 {
                     Classificacao.class_atletaNome,
                     Classificacao.class_numAtleta,
                     Classificacao.class_atletaEquipa,
                     Classificacao.class_paisAtleta,
                     Evento.even_name,
                     Evento.local.local_nome,
                     Evento.compTipo.CompTipo_name
                 } into g).ToList()
```

The idea is to materialize the query into a list before calling the methods.

```
                var model = group.Select(g => new
                 {
                     g.Key.class_numAtleta,
                     g.Key.class_atletaEquipa,
                     g.Key.class_atletaNome,
                     g.Key.class_paisAtleta,
                     class_fianlAtleta = g.Sum(c => c.class_fianlAtleta.Value),
                     class_classGeral = g.Min(c => c.class_fianlAtleta.Value),
                     class_nome = g.Key.even_name,
                     local_nome = g.Key.local_nome,
                     CompTipo_name = g.Key.CompTipo_name,
                     class_40ponto = ((from u in g
                                       where u.class_id_Evento == id_evento
                                       group u by new
                                       {
                                           u.class_atletaNome,
                                           u.class_fianlAtleta                                                  

                                       }
                                           into k
                                           select new
                                           {
                                               //Score = string.Concat(k.Key.class_fianlAtleta.ToString(), " + ", g.Key.class_atletaNome)
                                               Score = string.Format("{0}",k.Key.class_fianlAtleta)

                                           })).Select(c=>c.Score).FirstOrDefault()          


                 }).OrderBy(c => c.class_fianlAtleta).ThenBy(c => c.class_classGeral)).toList();
```

I can't check if the code is correct therefore I leave it to you, anyway once you have your List in memory you can apply the methods supported by Linq to entity.

Comment: Hi. Your code worked fine. Now the string.join work and the string.format works. TOP. But I have an another question: in my string.format he always get the same value and repeat it. How can the first, the second... for Thank you once again

Comment: @Francisco, please explain it better, I can't understand what you mean by "in my string.format he always get the same value and repeat it. How can the first, the second... for".

Comment: Hi, for example: An athelte may have more than one score in an season and the ideia is to show all of his scores in that season in a string with the following format: (5 +6+3) of that athlete. 1ª score + 2ª score+3ªscore...

Comment: @Francisco, you must use something like in my first reply: string.Join(" + ", t.Select(group => group.Score).ToArray()); I can't exactly understand from your code which are the correct properties, but in your group you have a list of object and in these object there is a property that represents the score, right? In the select, you must concatenate via string.Join all the scores of that group, selecting them and trasforming them into an array.

Comment: Hi, Worked Fine. Know it is working.:) Thank you very much for your help. Where can I put correct check on your comment.

Comment: @Francisco there is an arrow at the left of the comment, or better, you can click the up arrow at the left of the reply. Anyway I'm glad you worked out the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
        var result = table
            .GroupBy(t => new { t.Name, t.Event })
            .ToList()
            .Select(t => new
            {
                Name = t.Key.Name,
                JoinedScores = string.Join(" + ", t.Select(group => group.Score).ToArray()),
                TotalScore = t.Sum(group => group.Score).ToString() + " (Total Score)"
            }).ToList();
```

The first call to the `ToList()` method is needed because Linq to SQL will not support the calls to `string.Join()`. I'm not sure but probably you can replace it with a call to `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I have allready tried sting.Join, string.format and Aggregate  and allways get the following error:LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Francisco I have seen your new reply, I have added a new reply to explain you the strategy to follow.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I'm going to take a look,

Comment: Hi. Your code worked fine. Now the string.join work and the string.format works. TOP. But I have an another question: in my string.format he always get the same value and repeat it. How can the first, the second... for  Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
 var model = (from Classificacao in _dbSet.classificacao
                     from Evento in _dbSet.evento
                     where Classificacao.class_id_Evento == id_evento
                     where Evento.id_evento == id_evento
                     group Classificacao by new
                     {
                         Classificacao.class_atletaNome,
                         Classificacao.class_numAtleta,
                         Classificacao.class_atletaEquipa,
                         Classificacao.class_paisAtleta,
                         Evento.even_name,
                         Evento.local.local_nome,
                         Evento.compTipo.CompTipo_name
                     } into g

                     select new
                     {
                         g.Key.class_numAtleta,
                         g.Key.class_atletaEquipa,
                         g.Key.class_atletaNome,
                         g.Key.class_paisAtleta,
                         class_fianlAtleta = g.Sum(c => c.class_fianlAtleta.Value),
                         class_classGeral = g.Min(c => c.class_fianlAtleta.Value),
                         class_nome = g.Key.even_name,
                         local_nome = g.Key.local_nome,
                         CompTipo_name = g.Key.CompTipo_name,
                         class_40ponto = ((from u in g
                                           where u.class_id_Evento == id_evento
                                           group u by new
                                           {
                                               u.class_atletaNome,
                                               u.class_fianlAtleta                                                  

                                           }
                                               into k
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                   //Score = string.Concat(k.Key.class_fianlAtleta.ToString(), " + ", g.Key.class_atletaNome)
                                                   Score = string.Format("{0}",k.Key.class_fianlAtleta)

                                               })).Select(c=>c.Score).FirstOrDefault()          


                     }).OrderBy(c => c.class_fianlAtleta).ThenBy(c => c.class_classGeral);de here
```